# Heart Rate Monitor Simulator

Tags: c#, simulation, azure-sql-database, windows-phone

I am working on a Windows Phone Application. I need to develop a heart rate simulator using C#. This simulator will generate a value (BPM). Every time a value is generated, I will send it to my SQL-Azure database. I've done some searching but can not find anything that will help me simulate this.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Write the code that that generates BPM? Using Azure?

Comment: I think the problem is the algorithm to generate BPM and simulate different human situations (e.g. running, walking resting) How is this possible @svick. I think sending data to Azure should not be a problem

Comment: The problem is to write the code that generates the BPM. I was thinking about generating a random integer but it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am working on a Windows Phone Application

Do phones using Windows Phone have inbuilt heart rate monitors?

What you seem to say is:

- I need to come up with a number out of thin air

  > simulator will generate a value (BPM)
- then send this value to a SQL database.

I'll leave the "why would you want to do this" part out.

Your best bet is to find a list of typical BPM for various situations and generate a number, randomly, near these values.

You can sort of detect which situation you are in by using the accelerometer. If it says the phone is moving like crazy then select the "running" BPM, otherwise choose "sitting down" or "slow walk".

You can use your favorite search engine to look for "ECG wave simulator" to add some extra realism.